# NodeJS Stream flushed during the Event Loop iteration

Tags: node.js, event-loop, nodejs-stream

I'm trying to pipe one *Stream Axios Response* into multiple files. It's not working, and I can reproduce it with the simple code below:

Will work:

```
const { PassThrough } = require('stream')
const inputStream = new PassThrough()
inputStream.write('foo')
// Now I have a stream with content

inputStream.pipe(process.stdout)
inputStream.pipe(process.stderr)
// will print 'foofoo', for both stdout and stderr
```

Will not work:

```
const { PassThrough } = require('stream')
const inputStream = new PassThrough()
inputStream.write('foo')

inputStream.pipe(process.stdout)
setImmediate(() => {
    inputStream.pipe(process.stderr)
})
// Will print only 'foo'
```

The question is, Can I say that the existed content in the stream will be piped only if the two `pipe` commands will execute in the same Event-Loop iteration?

Doesn't that make the situation non-deterministic?

Answer (score 2):

By the time the callback scheduled with `setImmediate` is executed, the stream data is already flushed. This can checked by [.readableLength](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_readablelength) stream property.

You can use [cork](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_cork) and [uncork](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_uncork) in order to control when the buffered stream data is flushed.

```
const { PassThrough } = require('stream')
const inputStream = new PassThrough()
inputStream.cork()
inputStream.write('foo')
inputStream.pipe(process.stdout)
setImmediate(() => {
  inputStream.pipe(process.stderr)
  inputStream.uncork()
})
```